# How can I fix it?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have this following query :

```
SELECT parameter1, parameter1 
FROM kcrt_table_entries 
WHERE parameter_set_field_id = (SELECT parameter_set_field_id 
                                FROM knta_parameter_set_fields 
                                WHERE PROMPT = 'Matrix:'
                               )
  AND request_id = (SELECT kr.request_id 
                    FROM kcrt_requests kr 
                    WHERE kr.request_type_id = (SELECT request_type_id 
                                                FROM kcrt_request_types 
                                                WHERE request_type_name = 'RHB - Risk Rating Questionnaire'
                                               ) 
                      AND kr.status_id = (SELECT status_id 
                                          FROM kcrt_statuses 
                                          WHERE status_name = 'Admin-Reading'
                                         ) 
                   ) 
  AND parameter2 <  100 
  AND parameter3 >= 100
```

When I run it, it gives me the following error  :

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please provide a DDL of your tables. You have somewhere a string column which you try to convert to number. I suppose it is `parameter2` or `parameter3`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you selecting `PARAMETER1` twice?

As of the error you got: it seems that column names *should* match, at least by looking at their names (e.g. `request_id` to `request_id`, `status_id` to `status_id`, etc.) so all what remains are the last two lines:

```
AND parameter2 <  100 
AND parameter3 >= 100
```

If those columns' datatypes is not `NUMBER` but `VARCHAR2`, then you should enclose `100` into single quotes (i.e. use `'100'` instead).

If that doesn't help, do provide some additional info (description of tables would help).

Comment: It's for Visible and Hidden parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you meant to say.